# How can I test Google ads on my site

Tags: adsense

I am developing a website where I want to show Google ads. How can I test ads on my site? Additionally:

- Does Google allow me to test ads?
- Does it think my tests are fake impressions?
- Can I get blocked by Adsense?

here is site link http://www.geeksweblogs.com/

Comment: Yo need to create your google adsense account and register your website. Then google will check your site if it meets the requirements. Read also the google adsense policy.

Comment: i have google approved website running, But i want to experiment ads on my site all screen resolution. here is the link http://www.geeksweblogs.com/

Comment: I think this is a good way of generating traffic to your website, which is really necessary for your google adsense program.

Comment: @shishir I just want a solution for my problem , not really traffic

Answer (score 2):

Google may not like it, but in its TOS it says you are allowed to test your ads, although I would recommend you not to refresh the site thousands of times. Instead, I would first remove the AdSense tags and use some divs with fixed width & height and a background color (or a background image which looks like a Google ad) to test it excessively. If you have tested your layouts, remove the test divs and re-add your Google AdSense code. Now you can test it an additional few times to be 100% sure that all works. You can surely reload the page 10-20 times. Remember to just view the ads for testing but never ever click on your own ads – Google doesn't like that.